# super structure/class that contains other classes, that can be easily passed around

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

Is this data stucture possible using classes and what is it called in Python?

```
   class AwesomeThing():

       class Tv():
           tvid = ""
           queue = ""

       class Remote():
           remoteid = ""

       class Channel():
           channelid = ""

       class User():
           userid = ""

       class Comment():
           commentid = ""

       class Scene():
           sceneid = ""
           sceneurl = ""
```

And then I can get a instance like so....

```
     stream = AwesomeThing()
```

and set data to classes inside of it....

```
     stream.comment.msg = "that's cool"
     stream.user.userid = "EJJ1231"
     stream.channel.channelid = "#reactive"
     stream.scene.sceneurl = "http://coolvideo/iwanna?play.com"
```

and then send the whole instance with all the classes and its data set, off to a function...

```
     playyoutube(stream)
```

Comment: You can, more or less, but why would you want to?  There's no point in using nested classes for that.

Comment: You've made a dict of dicts, with slightly different syntax.  Just use a nested dict.

Comment: so take the class part off and make every thing dicts

Comment: but eventually i want to tie in functions to the added data fields, so like when one field gets changed a method is invoked, wouldnt that require class structure?

Comment: I see no point in doing this.
You can have a stream.comment, stream.userID, stream.channelid, stream.url, all in the same class. All in that class you can have your class methods that manipulate those variables.

Comment: then what is the point of a class? channel, comment, scene all have different behaviors and different data

Comment: there will be different tvs, different remotes, different channels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you have to give your Stream class a constructor (`__init__`) which creates instances of the nested classes as properties of your `AwesomeThing` class. For example, if I have this class:

```
class Post:
    class Score:
        upvotes = 0
        downvotes = 0
```

I would have to initialize an instance of the `Score` class inside the `Post` classes constructor:

```
class Post:
    class Score:
        upvotes = 0
        downvotes = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.score = Score()
```

I could then execute code like this:

```
my_post = Post()
my_post.score.upvotes = 8
```

So in your code, you'd have to add this to your `AwesomeThing` class:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.tv = Tv()
    self.remote = Remote()
    self.channel = Channel()
    self.user = User()
    self.comment = Comment()
    self.scene = Scene()
```

Comment: im getting recursion error...File "models.py", line 11, in __init__
    self.user = User()

Comment: class Thing(object):                                                                                                                                                    
        def __init__(self):
            self.tv = Tv()
            self.remote = Remote()
            self.channel = Channel()
            self.user = User()
            self.comment = Comment()
            self.scene = Scene()        
            self.locale = Locale()
           
class User():
        """Create User

Comment: You need to define the inner classes before you define __init__. If that doesn't work, define the classes outside of the `Thing` class.

Comment: Great :)! Hope I was helpful.